# C/C++ iOS to Android

Tags: android-ndk

I have a game written in C/C++ for iOS (using only obj-c for the GLES initialization) and I would like to port it to Android, I saw that it was possible using the NDK by creating a dynamic library (.so).

I install the Android SDK and NDK compile a simple library load it run, no problem, but I simply can't debug it... I can only debug the Java part (where my GLES context is created etc...) Am I missing something or? how can I debug my dynamic library?

It doesn't seems to have no support for debugging anything created with the NDK for Eclipse... so how am I suppose to debug my C/C++ then?

Anybody have experience with this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ndk-gdb`. Take a look at this articles:

- http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/web/debugging-through-the-jni-with-android-2-2
- http://www.eclipse.org/sequoyah/documentation/native_debug.php

Comment: Yeah I already try that, doesn't seems to work for me... Can someone confirm that this is actually working? Did I miss something or? Is there any other way?